# Archer GRC Report to find all records associated to a parent level record

Tags: report, rsa, archer, rsa-archer-grc

I'd like to create a report that will display all records in another application that are associated to a parent record in a multi-level application in Archer GRC. Is this possible? What if I want to filter to only a specific parent level record?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To filter by child record you could also choose that setting here:

1. Advanced Report Tool >
2. filters section
3. select "Filter by Record" >
4. choose to "only include the **CHILD** level record" you desire.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by only selecting the fields you need at the parent level record and ensure none of the fields for the child level records are selected within the **Advanced Search** of Archer GRC. Then create a relationship to the application whose records you want to associate with and select the fields you need there.

Now to ensure that you only get results for a specific parent level record, go to:

1. Advanced Report Tool >
2. filters section
3. select "**Filter by Record**" >
4. choose to *"only include the parent level record" you desire*.